# Sitecore Forms IViewModel and InputViewModel bool error

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

I am trying to get the value from the Sitecore forms in Sitecore(9.3). Actually, I am trying to hook up the `Mailchimp` with the  Sitecore forms, following the URL.
https://sitecoreguys.blogspot.com/2019/10/sitecore-forms-with-mailchimp.html
Everything works fine, except the bool value. I have a field in the form that has a checkbox. In the example all the values are strings.
I am not able to get the value of the checkbox.
it is failing

```
getFields.Add(((InputViewModel<string>)field).Title, ((InputViewModel<string>)field).Value);
```

the error I am getting

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.Bindings.CheckBoxViewWithBindingsTokenModel' to type 'Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.InputViewModel`1[System.String]'.'
```

The InputViewModel does not accept the bool value. I have tried to pass

```
((InputViewModel<bool>)field).Value) or 

((InputViewModel<string>)field).Value.to string)
```

What do I need to do to make the bool value work?
Thanks

Comment: Just cast it to `CheckBoxViewWithBindingsTokenModel` instead of casting to `InputViewModel<string>`

Comment: Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.CheckBoxViewModel  this thing worked for me. CheckBoxViewWithBindingsTokenModel did not. it could not find that.